# Meta data Along video in Youtube metadata Youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

Iam trying to upload the video but when file uploads the following response displays

**Video file name is missing: Slug header required.**

Code is

```
<form action="http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?
                access_token=ya29.AHES6ZQSxuX5deUDikYEa9iihA06w95he2kq95e4u2HFc3vAWT9giTk&
                key=AI39si7vDYyjPjmP7OKjN0ELwuW6k2geVKgwJqvDNVtLEsPotZJZ1OnRIfk519o7pabt_m8PQxKKp6Y9sUvbfxSx5M6JlhimQA&
                nexturl=http://localhost:8080/web/authorized.html" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">
      <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
      <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
        You need to specify a file.
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" id="access_token" value="TOKEN"/><br>
      <input type="submit" value="go" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Show your code for the upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some metadata's are missing. You have to send xml about video before uploading it.